# Extension of EM algorithm

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

[image]

How can I extened EM algorithm for two Gaussian distributions into three?

Answer (score 0):

You would have 3 weights, for example $\gamma_1$, $\gamma_2$ and $(1-\gamma_1-\gamma_2)$.

Like $p_1,p_2,p_3$ would be calculated in the same manner which also means the $\mu_i$s and $\sigma_i^2$s would similarly also.

Comment: Can it be proved too?